# Get length of csv file without ruining reader?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to do the following:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(self.file_path), delimiter='|')
reader_length = sum([_ for item in reader])
for line in reader:
    print line
```

However, doing the `reader_length` line, makes the reader itself unreadable. Note that I do not want to do a `list()` on the reader, as it is too big to read on my machine entirely from memory.

Comment: `[_ for item in reader]` *is* creating a `list()` on the whole reader.

Comment: I see -- how would I get around that then? How would I count it without destroying the reader -- or is that impossible? I suppose I could count the number of end-characters in the file?

Comment: You're basically reading the whole file twice.  Count them as you go in the for loop in one pass, or just close the file and open it again to reset the reader.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use enumerate with a start value of `1`, when you get to the end of the file you will have the line count:

```
for count,line in enumerate(reader,1):
    # do work
print count
```

Or if you need the count at the start for some reason sum using a generator expression and seek back to the start of the file:

```
  with open(self.file_path) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='|')
        count = sum(1 for _ in reader)
        f.seek(0)
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='|')
        for line in reader:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
reader = list(csv.DictReader(open(self.file_path), delimiter='|'))
print len(reader)
```

is one way to do this i suppose

another way to do it would be

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(self.file_path), delimiter='|')
for i,row in enumerate(reader):
    ...
num_rows = i+1
```

Comment: OP already stated he didn't want to do a `list()` on the whole reader.